# How can I inspect my mitre saw blade for damage?

Tags: safety, saw

So I did something stupid and tried to cut a piece of wood that was oddly shaped, too big for the saw, and badly clamped. When the blade hit the wood it sent it flying and some of the wood chips damaged the saw body itself. I can't imagine this was good for the blade. I am now very deeply worried about the blade, perhaps irrationally so, but I just have these visions that the saw will start spinning then shatter into a million pieces. Is that something I should be concerned about? Should I be worried about anything else? Is there a way to tell whether my saw is fine?

Comment: Key question is what is the blade made of? Sounds like you mean a metal blade, and as noted below, Mild Steel won't shatter under any circumstances, only bend/tear. If the blade is black and textured, then it is a metal-cutting disc, as used by angle-grinders, and those CAN shatter fairly violently.

Comment: @MikeBrockington it's a metal blade, yes.

Comment: Someone has changed the title of the question to a different one. Please don't change questions into different questions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Saw blades don't shatter. They may lose teeth, and they may warp. They won't come bodily apart from the incident you describe or any event short of an explosive shock. (I regularly use old ones as gongs for firearms target practice. Even then they don't shatter.)

Make a cut through soft wood to test the blade for a smooth, thin cut. Keep the workpiece tight against the table and fence. If it's warped you'll see a wide cut with a rough edge. Discard the blade as it's not repairable.

Your saw is fine if nothing seems loose and the motor, arm, and guard operate smoothly, as before. Give it a good looking-over and carry on.

Comment: I also have never seen this happen although I suppose it's possible in theory.  I'd remove the blade and carefully inspect it for damage.  Look for dents, cracks, bends, etc.  If none, then I'd use it.  If it bothers you new blades are not that expensive, get a new one.

Comment: I have to agree with Isherwood, I have tweaked blades good over the years and even use a hammer to straighten a bent tooth and other than having a carbide tip come off I have not seen a metal blade come apart (fiber ones for metal do but not metal for wood).

Comment: @jwh20 if it is a blade with carbide tips, then the body is made of the cheapest steel possible. That means that even if it is high-grade blade, cheapest steel that meets requirements will be springy, not hard - and thus not capable of shattering. There's simply no point to have high HRC on it. It was possible in theory in old all-metal blades if they were badly heat treated, but that's simply no longer an economical way to make blades, and mass production tends to get HRC too low, if anything.

Comment: @Mołot Re "It was possible in theory in old all-metal blades" - not only in theory. My friends father actually witnessed new saw blade to shatter while starting big bench-type circular saw - well, these were old soviet-times and tool quality was quite variable. Part of that saw blade was kept inside shop wooden wall, where it crashed - to remind about safety precautions :)

Comment: What safety precautions would a person take to defend against an exploding blade? Blast armor?

Comment: @isherwood Always stay out of the way of possible danger. (Sorry about my bad english.)

Answer (score 8):

If the shock to the blade was very severe it is possible that the arbor shaft of the motor to which the blade is mounted may get bent. This happened to me one time with a power miter saw I was using to cut some aluminum extrusion thresholds. Ribs in the extrusion on the under side caught on the blade teeth in a way so dramatic that over half of the carbide teeth on the 80 tooth 12" diameter blade were chipped or broken off.

It became very apparent that the arbor shaft got bent a very small amount when I tried powering up the saw for the first time with a new blade (12" high tooth count carbide tipped blades are far from low cost). There was a noticeable vibration of the motor. When manually turning the blade it was observed that there was run-out at the blade perimeter.

Result for safety reasons - Time to replace the miter saw.

Note that the ruined blade was never ever used again!

Answer (score 2):

> When the blade hit the wood it sent it flying and some of the wood chips damaged the saw body itself. I can't imagine this was good for the blade.

The blade itself might be your culprit. Something you might not be aware of is that saw teeth (especially if you bought a cheap blade) **can be sheared off**. A few years ago I went to cut a small 2x4 on my miter saw. I was maybe halfway through when the board exploded out of my hand and flew across the room. Luckily, I wasn't injured, but my hand really stung. Upon examining the blade, I noted three teeth in a row were missing. It was a cheap blade (the cheapest the big box sold), and I made sure not to repeat that mistake. I bought a much nicer one that I still use for the infrequent cuts I make.

If you want to avoid problems like this, don't lowball your blades (it sounds very much like this has cost you a saw). They do all the work and if they fail, that's where boards come back to bite you (or worse).

Answer (score 0):

Shattering would be almost impossible with a blade made for wood.

Would be concern about cracks in the blade that could cause a piece of the blade to break off during use.